# What is conjunctive truth table reduction?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, reference-request, complexity-classes, reductions, relativization

What are conjunctive/disjunctive truth table reductions and how do they compare with other reductions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the binary case they are two of the seven truth-table reducibilities
$$m, btt(1), c, d, p, \ell, tt$$
based on polynomial clones.
See Figure 1 in Culver's paper
https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00153-013-0351-x
for the classic diagram of the seven.

In the ternary case there are uncountably many such reducibilities instead of 7, as Culver demonstrates using a prior result about clones from universal algebra.

Comment: So only existence/non-existence of $m$ or many one is the only reducibility for proving class inclusions like $NP$ is in/not in $P$ and $tt$ suffices for $coNP$ in $P^{NP}$. What do the others give (other than they give tt)?

Comment: https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007%2Fs00153-013-0351-x.pdf gives $btt(1)$ implies $p$. What does norm $1$ mean? Is there illustrative examples that help understand both from hierarchy between $P$ and $PSPACE$?

Comment: @777 probably best to post that as a separate question or two.

Comment: @BjornKjosHanssen done.