# How to efficiently verify if a semantic symmetry of a CNF formula is valid?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, sat, permutations, symmetry

It is easy to verify that a syntactic symmetry of a CNF formula is correct.

Is it also possible to check in polynomial time that a semantic symmetry which is not a syntactic symmetry of a formula is correct?

What is the complexity of the problem of checking the validity of a CNF formula's semantic symmetry?

Note that a syntactic (resp. semantic) symmetry $\sigma$ of a CNF formula $F$ is a permutation of its literals such that for all literal $x$, $\sigma(\neg x)=\neg \sigma(x)$ and  $\sigma(F) = F$ (resp. $\sigma(F) \equiv F$).

Comment: It’s coNP-complete under ctt-reductions (and likely under many-one reductions as well).

Comment: @EmilJeřábek what are ctt-reductions?

Comment: Conjunctive truth-table reductions. In this case, it is enough to take the conjuction of two queries.

Comment: I found this post on ctt-reductions (https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/39858/what-is-conjunctive-truth-table-reduction) but it doesn't help me understanding how to proceed with the reduction. Please do you have any reference that could help me to first understand  conjunctive truth-table reductions and then to show the coNP-completeness of the problem?

Comment: A CNF is unsatisfiable iff (1) it is not satisfied by any of the $n+1$ assignments of the form $(0,\dots,0,1,\dots,1)$, and (2) it is semantically symmetric under all permutations. (1) can be checked directly in polynomial time, and in (2), it suffices to check two generators of Sym($n$) (say, an $n$-cycle and a transposition).

Comment: Is (1) necessary ? since when a CNF  is semantically symmetric under all permutations it is either unsatisfiable or a tautology. could (1) be replaced by the checking of only one assignment in order to verify that it is not a tautology?

Comment: $x_1\land\dots\land x_n$ is symmetric under all permutations and neither unsatisfiable nor a tautology.

Comment: Oh, you mean that your permutations can actually negate variables? Then yes, but the symmetry group is $C_2\wr S_n$, I would have to think if it’s still generated by $2$ elements.

Comment: Yes! I was thinking of a permutation like $(x_1,\neg x_1)$ which is not a semantic symmetry of $x_1\wedge\cdots \wedge x_n$.